# DataGrid - Displaying Running Total From Top of Grid Through Current Row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, collections

How would I display a running total for a particular column of each record that is displayed in a DataGrid? I'd like to keep the computation logic in the view model.

Desired Output:

```
Value      | Running Total
25           25
10           35
-2           33
```

Thank you,
Ben

**Edit:** Keep in mind that when a user-triggered DataGrid sort occurs, the running totals must be recalculated because the record display order has changed.

I'd really like to put the logic for this in the view model, not in WPF code (e.g. not using an IValueConverter).

Comment: Are you really asking how to iterate over a collection in order to calculate a sum? Otherwise this can be solved in the view using a valueconverter. What is the type of your collection and record? Does the record class have a total property? Do you support sorting? Updates of values?

Comment: @WP - I think the issue here is where to put the total, not how to get it. Your first inclination is to wonder if the grid can someway display a footer for you like excel can do. Cheers

Comment: @WP--I'm using an ObservableCollection<Item> holding Item objects. Yes, total property; yes, sorting; no, updating.

Comment: @WP -- No, I'm not asking how to iterate and sum a collection. How would you propose to do this with an IValueConverter?

Comment: If you want to calculate the totals in your VM just do it. Sorting need then be done in the VM as well. If user sorts, collection changes or values changes, you need to update all running totals and refresh the view.

Comment: @WP - How would you suggest tying the gird and the vm together so that the VM knows when the grid is resorted and so that the grid knows when the VM has resorted the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only idea: actually, DataGrid uses ICollectionView interface ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) to implement sorting (as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.95).aspx at **Grouping, Sorting, and Filtering** section.

So, you can create class that implements ICollectionView interface, and observe sorting with corresponding updating of running total.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there is a recommended / supported / simple way to do this. The choices I can think of are:
1) Have some ui element outside of the data grid to hold the total. This is easy to bind to your VM but a bit of a pain to work out the alignment issues that will come up, as you likely want the total right under the column. This is what I would recommend.
2) Have a dummy last row in the grid; this solves the alignment problem but adds hacky logic to the VM, and probably doesn't look so great on top of it.

HTH,
Berryl

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the answer in VB or C# then [this tutorial](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=84704) shows how to do what you want in VB and [this tutorial](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1609524&page=1) shows it in C#. Both use a dummy column in the grid.

Comment: yeah, I agree. I was thinking he wanted one total for a column to go underneath it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer for how to add a row count column to a ListBox and populate using a value converter. Instead of counting item, add up the sum of items. If you need the total sum in your VM this is of course not a good solution.

[Numbered listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox/748383#748383)

Comment: Did you have the link for the answer you mentioned?

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Thanks for sharing it. One of the neat things about it is that the objects in the collection passed to the grid's ItemsSource need not have a Balance property.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by extending DataGrid to expose a property which could be bound to a "resort has occured" callback on the view model.

Details: http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/07/14/3/datagrid-per-row-running-totals

Answer (score 0):

```
long cumulative = 0;
List<int> Values = GetValues();
Values.ForEach(v => v.RunningTotal = cumulative = cumulative + v.Value);
```

You can just run **foreach** for the whole list and get your running total by the formula 
**(RunningTotal = cumulative = cumulative + Value);**
We need to continously save the previous value.