# WPF: Binding lists in XAML- how can an item know its position in the list?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, list, xaml

Given the following XAML code that with a ListControl like behavior:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Name="_listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_userControl, Path=DataContext}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                         ...
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

Since the list can be long (100-200 items), and the items look similar, I think it would helpful for the user during scrolling if every item would display their position in the list. **How could an item in the template know its own position in the list?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a hack solution. We can use Value Conversion with DataBinding. So the first step is to declare our ValueConvertor:

```cs
public class ListItemToPositionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region Implementation of IValueConverter

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var item = value as ListBoxItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                var lb = FindAncestor<ListBox>(item);
                if (lb != null)
                {
                    var index = lb.Items.IndexOf(item.Content);
                    return index;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }            

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Declare wherever you want this static method in order to obtain ListBox parent:

```cs
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject from) where T : class
        {
            if (from == null)
                return null;

            var candidate = from as T;
            return candidate ?? FindAncestor<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(from));
        }
```

Then in ListBox.Resources declare our convertor as follows:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
                <YourNamespace:ListItemToPositionConverter x:Key="listItemToPositionConverter"/>
            </ListBox.Resources>
```

And finally - DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Converter={StaticResource listItemToPositionConverter}}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**Note:** in this example the items will be numerated starting with 0 (zero), you can change it in Convert method by adding 1 to result.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/default.aspx) article "[Charting with DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/ee413725.aspx)":

> [...]the DataTemplate would need access to the index of the particular data item in the collection. But it's easy enough to include this information in the business object[...]

So, unless there was a change in .NET 4, there is no "index of this item" property unless it is explicitly included in the model.

Answer (score 0):

This sample supports sorting:

[Numbered listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox/748383#748383)