# wpf,How to show index of Collection in bind?

Tags: wpf

ListBox had been binded to a Collection of string,I want to Button control to show index of element in collection.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                            <Button Height="20" Width="20" Content="{Binding ???}"  Margin="2">
                            </Button>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check these links.You may find what you are looking for

[WPF: Binding lists in XAML- how can an item know its position in the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607368/wpf-binding-lists-in-xaml-how-can-an-item-know-its-position-in-the-list)

[Numbered listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox/748383)

If you follow the approach described by 'Seven' in [Numbered listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox/748383)
 the your code should look something like

```
<Button Height="20" Width="20" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplatedParent.(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"  Margin="2">
```

Comment: +1, was thinking of something similar. Two things: 1) You'll probably want to set AlternationCount to something like 100000 in the ListBox. Otherwise they'll all have 0 as number. 2) The numbering will start from 0 and not 1 so you might want to use a converter and increase the value by 1