# How can I access the same property in different objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oop, mvvm

Imagine I have this class:

```
Class Foo
{
    public Bar b1 { get; set; }
    public Bar b2 { get; set; }
    public Bar b3 { get; set; }

    public void UpdateBarsMyProp(bool value)
    {
        // ????
    }
}

Class Bar
{
    public bool MyProp { get; set; }

    public bool UpdateMyProp(bool value)
    {
        this.MyProp = value;
    }
}
```

What's the best way to update the property MyProp in b1, b2 and b3?

Generics?

Delegates?

**EDIT:**

Just to add more information about my specific situation:

I'm creating a virtual keyboard and I'm using WPF MVVM so I have:

A KeyBoard ViewModel which contains several Key ViewModels, I can't store them in a List because im my View (xaml file) I need to bind each key information to a specific ViewModel.

Now, when the user presses the virtual shift button, I need my Keyboard ViewModel object to update the display char in every Key ViewModel.

Comment: Write 3 simple lines calling the method on each of them?

Comment: `b1.MyProp = b2.MyProp = b3.MyProp = value;`?

Comment: If all your objects share the same value you can make MyProp static. Then Bar.MyProp = x;

Comment: @CodesInChaos, and what If I had 50 objects?

Comment: Then you should keep them in some kind of collection...

Comment: Thank you @Ossie7, please submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm done editing http://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.com/a/12213381/659190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your properties in a `List<Bar>` (or an array if you prefer...) and iterate over it.

So:

```
public Bar b1 { get; set; }
public Bar b2 { get; set; }
public Bar b3 { get; set; }
// other Bar props...

private List<Bar> barsList = new List<Bar>(){ b1, b2, b3, ... };

public void UpdateBarsMyProp(bool value)
{
    foreach(Bar bar in barsList)
    {
        bar.MyProp = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll need to store them in a List just because of this requirement.

Comment: I'm not saying to remove `Bar` properties. You can maintain them in your class to bind to xaml controls. however you can also have a private list/array of Bars that contains all your properties references. so you can easily assign common values to them

Comment: @EduardoBrites but you'll have to maintian the bar properties for enternity why not bind to a public indexer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your example is simplfied, but why not just do

```
b1.MyProp = b2.MyProp = b3.MyProp = value;
```

Also, why bother with the `UpdateMyProp` method? This is the same as the property setter method you have. If you need to add more logic to the setter, you can stop using the auto-implemented property by changing

```
public bool MyProp { get; set; }
```

to

```
private bool myProp;

public bool MyProp
{
   get { return this.myProp; }
   set
   {
      // any logic here
      this.myProp = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your bar objects require the same MyProp, you can set MyProp as static:

```
public static bool MyProp { get; set; }
```

You can then edit all MyProps of all bar objects with:

```
Bar.MyProp = baz;
```

Only use this if ALL the Bar objects share the same MyProp

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want somthing like this.

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly IList<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>
        {
            new Bar(),
            new Bar(),
            new Bar()
        }

    public Bar this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
           return this.bars[i];
        }
    }

    public void UpdateBars(bool value)
    {
        foreach (var bar in this.bars)
        {
            bar.MyProp = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then access the first bar like this

```
var foo = new Foo();
var firstBar = foo[0];
```

You can [bind to a indexer with a little convertor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511619/wpf-bind-to-indexer), this would make your model less brittle.

---

if you didn't want to use an indexer, you could raise a setter to `Foo`.

```
Class Foo
{
    public Bar b1 { get; set; }
    public Bar b2 { get; set; }
    public Bar b3 { get; set; }

    public bool MyProp
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.b1 != null)
            {
                this.b1.MyProp = value;
            }

            if (this.b2 != null)
            {
                this.b2.MyProp = value;
            }

            if (this.b3 != null)
            {
                this.b3.MyProp = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```