# Bind to some embedded object properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a Cars `IEnumerable`:

```
public IEnumerable<ICars> Cars { get; private set; }
```

The object "Car" actually contains a reference to another object of type IBrand:

```
public interface ICar
{
    // Parent brand accessor
    IBrand Brand { get; set; }

    // Properties
    int CarId { get; set; }
    string CarName { get; set; }
}
```

The IBrand interface has some properties:

```
public interface IBrand
{
    // Properties
    string LogoName { get; set; }
    string Sector { get; set; }
}
```

I am binding this Cars IEnumerable to a DataGrid - **this workds perfectly fine**:

```
<DataGrid Name="Cars"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Car Id"
                        Binding="{Binding CarId}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Car Name"
                        Binding="{Binding CarName}"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

**My problem is that I'd like to bind some properties from the Brand as well** (common to all the cars), like for example the logo. **This synthax doesn't work though**:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Logo Name"
                    Binding="{Binding Brand.LogoName}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Any idea on how to do so? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a dotted path you need to specify the `Path` keyword explicitly. This should work:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Logo Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Brand.LogoName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Will add the "Path" everywhere in that case, no point to gain 4 chars compared to the pain to find where its not missing! Cheers