# Show the item index in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a combo bind to an item-source. I want to display the index of item as DisplayMemberPath instead of any property of the binded object.

How can I achieve the same.

Comment: How about showing us what you tried...?

Comment: Can we see some code? And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to write a converter but not able to figure out how to proceed and pass the item source to converter. Also is it appropriate to pass the item source to converted

Comment: And what do you mean "display _index of item_"? Display the location it shows up in the ComboBox? Or in your ItemsSource?

Comment: Index of item is same as index in items source

Comment: Index is not a property of the item.  Why not just create a property Index and populate it when you create the collection?

Comment: Want to do something like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607368/wpf-binding-lists-in-xaml-how-can-an-item-know-its-position-in-the-list) but do not want to override data template as screws my themening some how.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a MultiValueConverter by passing in the collection and the current item and then returning the index of the item in the item collection:

```
public class ItemToIndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var itemCollection = value[0] as ItemCollection;
        var item = value[1] as Item;

        return itemCollection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="MainComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboSourceItems}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <cvtr:ItemToIndexConverter x:Key="ItemToIndexConverter" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Item}">
            <Label>
                <Label.Content>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemToIndexConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Items" ElementName="MainComboBox" />
                        <Binding />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ItemsSource` to something like this:

```
public List<Tuple<int,YourObject>> MyItems {get;set;} //INotifyPropertyChanged or ObservableCollection

public void PopulateItems(List<YourObject> items)
{
     MyItems = items.Select(x => new Tuple<int,YourObject>(items.IndexOf(x),x)).ToList();
}


<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Item1"/>
```