# Is possible to get a index from a item in a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I mean, I've got a listBox, and I'm putting in itemsSource property the list. And I want to show also the index in the binding of it.

I have no idea if this is possible in WPF. Thanks.

Comment: almost anything is possible in WPF--with the right XAML/codebehind combination

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few methods for doing this including [some workarounds using the AlternationIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox/3729021#3729021).

However, since I've used the AlternationIndex for other purposes I like to get a binding for the element index with the following:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource indexOfConverter}">
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
    <Binding Path="."/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Where the converter is defined as:

```
public class IndexOfConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Designer.IsInDesignMode) return false;

        var itemsControl = values[0] as ItemsControl;
        var item = values[1];
        var itemContainer = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

        // It may not yet be in the collection...
        if (itemContainer == null)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        var itemIndex = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(itemContainer);
        return itemIndex;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return targetTypes.Select(t => Binding.DoNothing).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `ItemsControl.Items.IndexOf(values[1])`?

Comment: I believe that the `Items` collection contains the UIElements rather than the actual item being bound to.

Comment: No, it does not, if that was the case those methods on the ItemContainerGenerator would be superfluous.

Comment: Are you sure? I was basing that assumption on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx

Comment: Cool! Well there you go. Learn something new every day. Well, the code in my post still stands because I know it works - I've used it in production code. Though as per @H.B. that is the long way round.

Comment: nice approch,but it doesn't work for int[], lets says all values are equls.
how can i overcome this?