# Bind list of models to items in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

```
<ScrollViewer Width="600" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              PanningMode="Both" 
              extensions:TouchScrolling.IsEnabled="True" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Width="175" 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="170" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Grid MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=backgroundImage, Path=ActualWidth}" >
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Image Height="160" 
                                   Source="man.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Grid.Row="1" 
                           FontSize="10" 
                           Text="Bomber jacket..." />
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Border Width="175" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1">...
        </Border>
        <Border Width="175" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="2">...
        </Border>
        <Border Width="175" 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="3">...
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have above xaml. In scrollViewer i have some items. I want to initialize it with data from database. How to do this?

I need to screate some `ItemControl` for common XAML and bind to properties. But how can i manage to bind every item in list to be binded to that `ItemControl` ?

---

I found [this topic](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) where i understand how to build same xaml for list items, but one problem is there - How to set Grid.Column for each item?

Comment: So why can't you use an items control, a grid or listview or listbox. What is the exact problem, because just showing us your scrollviewer doesn't help.

Comment: @TYY, please check my update - now it seems to be much more clear for me, but still one problem

Comment: This question is far from clear. What _specifically_ are you trying to accomplish? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you're trying to do. Also provide a precise, specific explanation of what that code does now, and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` is used to draw a UI for a collection of items.

So to start with, you need your collection of items from the database.

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection { get; set; }
```

To draw this using an ItemsControl, you would use XAML like this :

```
<ScrollViewer Height="100">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

This will use the default UI for an ItemsControl, which is to loop through each item in the collection, and for each one render a TextBlock with the Text property displaying the `.ToString()` of the item.

So what actually renders is something like

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock /> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[0] -->
        <TextBlock /> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[1] -->
        <TextBlock /> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[2] -->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The ItemsControl lets you modify different parts of the template though.

For example, to change the `<StackPanel>` in the XAML above, you would set the `ItemsPanel` property to use a Grid instead.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Or to change the `TextBlock` to something else, you could change the ItemTemplate

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Width="175" ...>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This would make your output render something like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Width="175" ...> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[0] -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Border>

        <Border Width="175" ...> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[1] -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Border>

        <Border Width="175" ...> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[2] -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

To set Grid.Column, it's actually a bit trickier. An ItemsControl actually wraps each item in a `<ContentPresenter>` so each item in the XAML above would actually render more like this :

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <Border Width="175" ...> <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[0] -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Border>
</ContentPresenter>
```

To set a property like `Grid.Column`, it needs to be set on the `ContentPresenter` that wraps each item. And that's what the `ItemContainerStyle` is used for.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

So assuming you were binding to

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection { get; set; }
```

and `MyItem` looked like this

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your final XAML might look something like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                    Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                    Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="175" ...>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And it would render something like this :

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[0] -->
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex}" Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnIndex}">
            <Border Width="175" ...> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Border>
        </ContentPresenter>

        <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[1] -->
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex}" Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnIndex}">
            <Border Width="175" ...> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Border>
        </ContentPresenter>

        <!-- DataContext is MyCollection[2] -->
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex}" Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnIndex}">
            <Border Width="175" ...> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Border>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very cool explanation. Just one question about `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` - can I somehow set it as number of item in collection? without adding property for it?

Comment: Ooops, don't worry - i found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30324533/3917754 seems to be good

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right what you mean is that you want to bind a list of items to your xaml. To do this you can use a `GridView`.

In a Gridview you bind a list of items and define a template for each of these items.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
                    <Gridview.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding foo}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>
```

As you can see. the gridview items template defines how each item in the list is going to be displayed. When you overwrite the itemspanel you can  set `MaximumRowsOrColumns` and `Orientation` to define how many items each row will have and which way the rows are facing.