# How to get binding Index for TabItems' Header, like "Page_1", "Page_2", "Page_3"

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol

I have Binding a ObservableCollection to ItemSource.
And I set the Item Header Property Style to binding a string.

I want it can display the Header Like `Page 1`, `Page 2` etc.. according to the binding object index.
How Can I do something in the TabControl_Header' get function in VM Class?

View

```
<Style x:Key="_HeaderString" TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DataContext.TabControl_Header , Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
</Style>
```

ViewModel

```
public string TabControl_Header
{
    get { return "Page_"+???; }            
}
```

Comment: I would say that the object you set in your TabItem show have that info. and when you create the collection you pass the corresponding index to the element.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378456/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-current-itemscontrol-item