# WPF/ItemsControl How to Bind to Index of Another Collection Using AlternationIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

Let me preface this by saying, I'm not sure if this is even possible. I've got two similar collections of complex objects that I'm using as source data for two different Items controls. Well, let's call the first collection the `old` data, and let's call the second collection the `new` data.

Like I said above, I've got two items controls - one binding to `old`, and the other binding to `new`. Well, in the item template of the `new` items control, I want to be able to bind to the `old` data, however I need to be able to use an index because the property is List of items. Maybe code snippets will help explain what I'm after:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Textblock Text="{Binding Path=OldSourceData.MyList[0]}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

However, I need to replace `0` with the alternation index of the current item. I'm using this to get the correct index `{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`

How do I replace `0` with the alternation index?

***EDIT***
I'm trying to figure out how to do something like this: `<Textblock Text="{Binding Path=OldSourceData.MyList[{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}]}"/>` Obviously, this syntax doesn't work, however is it possible to accomplish this somehow?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378456/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-current-itemscontrol-item

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy It's not a duplicate. I can grab the alternation index using the above code, however is it possible to put that code inside of the square brackets ```[0]``` when accessing an item from ```OldSourceData```?

Comment: Not possible to put inside, but you can use converter to do that, like in link provided. Also if you want to put it inside you need to create your own MarkupExtension