Background of Tab Control Header of index specified in view model turns a different colour
First time posting a question on here, so forgive me if I make any mistakes.
I have a counter called TurnNumber. This number changes dynamically, based on buttons at the top of the screen. I want to change the colour of the background of the tab whose index equals the TurnNumber.
This is what I have at the moment
MainWindowView:
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DndBattleHelper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DnD Battle Helper" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:DndBattleHelper.ViewModels"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:DndBattleHelper.Views"
        xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:DndBattleHelper.Views.Converters"
        Name="main">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <VM:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:TwoEqualNumbersToBooleanConverter x:Key="TwoEqualNumbersToBooleanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Previous Turn" Command="{Binding PreviousTurnCommand}"/>
                <Button Content="Next Turn" Command="{Binding NextTurnCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding EntitiesInInitiative}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}">
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TwoEqualNumbersToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="&lt;">
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" />
                                        <Binding Path="DataContext.TurnNumber" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                </DataTrigger.Setters>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:EnemyViewModel}">
                        <Views:EnemyView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:PlayerViewModel}">
                        <Views:PlayerView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.Resources>
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- this is the header template-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Converter:
    public class TwoEqualNumbersToBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length < 2)
                return false;

            int number1 = (int)values[0];
            int number2 = (int)values[1];

            // Return true if the tab index matches the TurnNumber
            return number1 == number2;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

TurnNumber is passed in correctly, and I trigger the converter each time it changes. Currently it appears that I am passing the wrong value for "Tab item index", as I call the converter 3 times, but every time the value 0 is passed in. This means that when TurnNumber = 0, then the converter actually returns true:
When TurnNumber = 0
However, it changes all of the tab items to be red, rather than just the one whose index equals TurnNumber.
I would also like this to override SelectedTab colours, so that the selected tab is the standard grey, the TurnNumber tab is red, but if the TurnNumber Tab is also the Selected Tab, then it is Red. Currently Grey overrides the red.
Thank you!

What's Happening
It seems to me you might be misusing or misunderstanding ItemsControl.AlternationIndex a bit. From the Microsoft documentation:

The AlternationCount and ItemsControl.AlternationIndex properties enable you to specify the appearance for two or more alternating item containers. For example, you can specify alternating background colors for every third item in an ItemsControl.

AlterationIndex doesn't give you the absolute index of the item, it gives you the index of the item within each group of n items. It's intended to be used with ItemsControl.AlternationCount.
For example, if you had AlternationCount="2" on your TabControl:

The first tab would have ItemsControl.AlternationIndex == 0
The second would have ItemsControl.AlternationIndex == 1
The third would have ItemsControl.AlternationIndex == 0

This is because the third tab would be the first item in the second group, each group being two items in size (AlternationCount="2").
I suspect that if AlternationCount is not set at all, then all items would have AlternationIndex == 0, which would explain what you are seeing.
My Answer
At first glance, I would think that setting AlternationCount to equal the number of tabs you have might make this work, but judging from this, that does not seem to be reliable.
Since you're already creating a IMultiValueConverter, I think the right way to approach this is to add the TabControl as a third input value. You could then use ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer to get the index of the given item and compare it to your input. For further help on doing that, here is an existing answer that shows you how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290188/5086631

Thank you! This is what I needed and it is now working as intended. I have bound TabControl.ItemsControl.AlternationCount to a new EntitiesInInitativeCount property. As you explained, this then would present an issue where when adding new items to the list the AlternationIndex would not update (and so when TurnNumber was 0, EntetiesInInitiativeCount was now 4 instead of 3, both indexes 0 and 3 where highlighted). I added a PropertyChanged(string.empty) call after I add new items to the list, to refresh the xaml (and therefore update the AlternationIndex), and seems to be working as intended.

Would it be better to pass in TabControl as a third input from a best practice point of view? The main point I can think of is that it can be easy to introduce an issue, as the dev needs to remember to add an property changed call every time when modifying the list.

The main reason I would suggest to not use AlteractionCount like this, is because it seemingly doesn't always work as expected. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511180/wpf-itemscontrol-the-current-listitem-index-in-the-itemssource/17962582#17962582
