# How to bind data together with the item index on Windows Phone 8

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have an `ItemsControl` in my ApplicationPage.xaml and I'm binding data to it with the following code:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="24" Text="{Binding someData}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want it to also display the item index next to `someData`, such that if the bound strings are `{"First string", "Second string", "Third string", ...}`, it would look like:

1. First string
2. Second string
3. Third string

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/745659/2998271), except that one was using ListBox

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] someData = { "First string", "Second string", "Third string" };

for (int i = 0; i < someData.Length; i++)
{ someData[i] = i.ToString() + someData[i]; }
```

This could do what you want, but if you want to add these number like an another binding object, You should create a class and it should contains "number" and "content" variables. And then you can bind them.

If first solution won't enough for you, I can help you about creating classes and binding them.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)
Those are alignment and formatString in index [,alignment] [:formatString].

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding SomeDate,StringFormat='{}stuff happened on {0,10:d}'} />
```