# Getting index from ListBox that uses CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol, collectionviewsource

Is there any way to make AlternationCount avoid resetting for each new CollectionViewSource? Given the code underneath I am trying to alternate backgrounds between messages. The messages are grouped into days (today, yesterday, 2 days ago etc), and this is what ruins the AlternationCount. Say I want odd indexes to have a white background and even indexes to have a gray one, this will be reset for each new day/group.

```
<ItemsControl AlternationCount="2">
  <ItemsControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MessagesStackPanel" Source="{Binding Messages}">
      <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MessageDate" />
      </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Backgrounds are set with a setter like this

```
<Grid.Style>
  <Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

An example would be the following, say I got 3 messages today, 2 yesterday, and 4 messages two days ago - the backgrounds of them would be like this:

White

```
Gray
```

White

---

White

```
Gray
```

---

White

```
Gray
```

White

```
Gray
```

This will leave me with a double White background between today and yesterday which really breaks the design. Is there a way to have AlternationIndex *not* reset for each new group?

Answer (score 0):

You get this because each group is a separate set of items.
It counts per item within a group.
I don't know of any way of retaining grouping yet keeping that alternationcount across items.

You could instead add a property of your own to the viewmodel representing each message.
You could set that in code as you read the data in.

Comment: I would have to set it somewhere around where the CollectionViewSource does it's job, as that is what sets the order. I'll look into this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's wise to forget about ItemsControls if you want to have control over your indexes (when using CollectionViewSource). The answer to my problem could eventually be found in this link right here:

[Numbered listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745568/numbered-listbox)

I first had to change my ItemsControl to a ListBox, then all I needed was a converter explained in *Wallstreet Programmer*'s answer in the post I linked. Now I have full control of my indexes and can adjust my backgrounds accordingly. Seems like a lot of unneccessary steps for something that I would think should have a way cheaper and easier solution, but at least it works.

EDIT: This does not work. After leaving it on overnight and sending myself a few extra messages the morning after I am not left with the following set of indexes:

1 2

---

1 2 3

---

2 3

The converter from the example as is adds 1 to the index, that's why it's 1 2, and not 0 1. Doesn't matter for alternating for me anyway. In this particular example it would work, but just by chance. The list is not numbered how I want it to be, but nevertheless it alternates between odd and even.

Comment: Is there any way to force my View to re-render all of the items every time it notices a new message? Right now it adds in new messages with the right index, but it seems that it just leaves whatever comes after as is, breaking the whole logic.